# jquery: $(this).data('id-site') always return the first value I clicked on

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<button data-id-site="359319" class="btn btn-warning detailparc"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> Details</button>
<button data-id-site="56541" class="btn btn-warning detailparc"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> Details</button>
<button data-id-site="32641" class="btn btn-warning detailparc"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> Details</button>
<button data-id-site="012438" class="btn btn-warning detailparc"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> Details</button>
<button data-id-site="545123" class="btn btn-warning detailparc"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> Details</button>
```

this is my Html code

```
$(function(){
    $(".detailparc").click(function(){
        html = '<div class="modal fade" id="modalDetailParc">';
        html+= '<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">';
        html+= '<div class="modal-content">';
        html+= '<div class="modal-header">';
        html+= '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"';
        html+= 'aria-label="Close">';
        html+= '<span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>';
        html+= '</button>';
        html+= '<h4 class="modal-title">Detail Parc</h4>';
        html+= '</div>';
        html+= '<div class="modal-body">';
        html+= $(this).data('id-site');
        html+= '</div>';
        html+= '<div class="modal-footer">';
        html+= '<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Fermer</button>';
        html+= '</div>';
        html+= '</div>';
        html+= '</div>';
        html+= '</div>';

        $("#parc").append(html);
        $("#modalDetailParc").modal('show');
    });
});
```

And that's my jquery code

I want to retrieve the content of the data-id-site attribute.
when I click on a button in the first time everything is fine, but when I click on an other button I always get the value of the first button I clicked on :/

Comment: `$("#parc").on('click','.detailparc',function(){`

Comment: it seems works fine https://jsfiddle.net/gzcm5dkh/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this code to run it as expected. Its only bacuse you will have to clear field before appending next time to clear previous value by this code

```
jQuery("#parc .modal").remove();
```

```js
jQuery(function($){
    jQuery(".detailparc").click(function(){
        html = '<div class="modal fade" id="modalDetailParc">';
        html+= '<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">';
        html+= '<div class="modal-content">';
        html+= '<div class="modal-header">';
        html+= '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"';
        html+= 'aria-label="Close">';
        html+= '<span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>';
        html+= '</button>';
        html+= '<h4 class="modal-title">Detail Parc</h4>';
        html+= '</div>';
        html+= '<div class="modal-body">';
        html+= jQuery(this).data('id-site');
        html+= '</div>';
        html+= '<div class="modal-footer">';
        html+= '<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Fermer</button>';
        html+= '</div>';
        html+= '</div>';
        html+= '</div>';
        html+= '</div>';
        
        jQuery("#parc .modal").remove(); 
        jQuery("#parc").append(html);
        //jQuery("#modalDetailParc").modal('show');
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button data-id-site="359319" class="btn btn-warning detailparc"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> Details</button>
<button data-id-site="56541" class="btn btn-warning detailparc"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> Details</button>
<button data-id-site="32641" class="btn btn-warning detailparc"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> Details</button>
<button data-id-site="012438" class="btn btn-warning detailparc"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> Details</button>
<button data-id-site="545123" class="btn btn-warning detailparc"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> Details</button>

<div id='parc'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to retrieve the content of the data-id-site attribute:

```
$(this).attr('data-id-site');
```

instead of,

```
$(this).data('id-site');
```

Answer (score 0):

**So here is your problem you have to do**

```
$(".detailparc").on('click', function() {

    var = siteId = $(this).data("id-site");

    html = '<div class="modal fade" id="modalDetailParc">';
    html+= '<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">';
    html+= '<div class="modal-content">';
    html+= '<div class="modal-header">';
    html+= '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"';
    html+= 'aria-label="Close">';
    html+= '<span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>';
    html+= '</button>';
    html+= '<h4 class="modal-title">Detail Parc</h4>';
    html+= '</div>';
    html+= '<div class="modal-body">';
    html+= siteId;
    html+= '</div>';
    html+= '<div class="modal-footer">';
    html+= '<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Fermer</button>';
    html+= '</div>';
    html+= '</div>';
    html+= '</div>';
    html+= '</div>';

    $("#parc").append(html);
    $("#modalDetailParc").modal('show');
});
```

**Check it like this and tell me**

Answer (score 0):

Try it like below:

```js
$(function(){
    $(document).on('click','.detailparc',function(){
        /*html = '<div class="modal fade" id="modalDetailParc">';
        html+= '<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">';
        html+= '<div class="modal-content">';
        html+= '<div class="modal-header">';
        html+= '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"';
        html+= 'aria-label="Close">';
        html+= '<span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>';
        html+= '</button>';
        html+= '<h4 class="modal-title">Detail Parc</h4>';
        html+= '</div>';
        html+= '<div class="modal-body">';
        html+= $(this).data('id-site');
        html+= '</div>';
        html+= '<div class="modal-footer">';
        html+= '<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Fermer</button>';
        html+= '</div>';
        html+= '</div>';
        html+= '</div>';
        html+= '</div>';

        $("#parc").append(html);
        $("#modalDetailParc").modal('show');*/
        alert($(this).data('id-site'));
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button data-id-site="359319" class="btn btn-warning detailparc"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> Details - 359319</button>
<button data-id-site="56541" class="btn btn-warning detailparc"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> Details - 56541</button>
<button data-id-site="32641" class="btn btn-warning detailparc"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> Details - 32641</button>
<button data-id-site="012438" class="btn btn-warning detailparc"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> Details - 012438</button>
<button data-id-site="545123" class="btn btn-warning detailparc"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> Details - 545123</button>
```